# boost::optional abstract class type

Tags: c++, boost, abstract-class, option-type

I would like to have an optional object of an abstract type.
However, boost::optional fails for abstract types:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
class A { 
  virtual int getInt() = 0; 
};
class B : public A {
  int getInt() { return 666; };
};

int main() {
  boost::optional<A> maybeAnA;
  boost::optional<A> another(maybeAnA);
};
```

results in

```
error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘A’
```

Just using a pointer doesn't seem a viable solution either, since some function needs to return an object containing the optional value as member, though it is not logical to expect the caller of the function to be the owner of that member variable.

Comment: Regarding pointers and ownership, if you want the "ownership" of a pointer to be transferable, why not use e.g. [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (or the Boost equivalent)?

Comment: If you /do/ want `optional` to act as a container of the type, you should indeed use `unique_ptr<A>` (it's already nullable, transferrable and owns the resource).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Optional  has value semantics, so you cannot do what you want for the same reason that you cannot instantiate `A` itself:

```
A anA;
```

Because you seem to be interested in *referring* to an optional value, instead of *owning/containing* it:

You can have an optional containing a reference:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/optional_references.html

> This library allows the template parameter `T` to be of reference type: `T&`, and to some extent, `T const&`.
>
> However, since references are not real objects some restrictions apply and some operations are not available in this case:
>
> - Converting constructors
> - Converting assignment
> - InPlace construction
> - InPlace assignment
> - Value-access via pointer

This way you can have exactly the same as when passing `A&`, *but optional*

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6031ab43c23c27c)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

struct A { 
  virtual int getInt() = 0; 
};

struct B : A {
  int getInt() { return 666; }
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  boost::optional<A&> maybeAnA;
  
  B b;
  maybeAnA = b; // non owning, just the reference
  
  boost::optional<A&> another(maybeAnA);
  
  std::cout << another->getInt();
}
```

Prints

```
666
```

If you /do/ want `optional` to act as a container of the type, you should indeed use `unique_ptr<A>` (it's already nullable, transferrable and owns the resource).

Comment: I had been looking a bit into `unique_ptr`s, but didn't understand how to move them around. Now that I know I can `std::move` a `unique_ptr` returned by some function into some member for example, I see how they are useful.

Comment: That's the hall mark of a _move-only_ type. If you need to transfer ownership, use that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it the way you want.

optional tries to create a member of type `A` (in your case) and fails doing it.

The only solution which comes to my mind and which I use is to store (smart) pointers.